# Python Web Scraping - Failed to extract a list from the website

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, selector

I failed to extract the first column "Name" from the website. Is there anyone who can help? [Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHHfm.jpg)
The website address is: https://www.wilsonship.no/our-fleet/fleetlist
Many thanks

```py
from scrapy import Selector
import requests

url = 'https://www.wilsonship.no/our-fleet/fleetlist'
html = requests.get(url).content
sel = Selector(text = html)
shipname = sel.xpath('//tr/td[1]/a/text()').extract()
shipname
```

Comment: The data is generated with JavaScript so you need to get around it. Did you read scrapy's [doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/)? Why don't you create a spider? BTW, you didn't accept any answers for your previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely dynamically writes the data using JavaScript.
You could use libraries like Selenium or Dryscape to get the data.

You might want to look into [Web Scraping JavaScritp page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python?rq=1). Or, if you insist on using scrapy, look into [Selecting dynamically-loaded content](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html).